# narrow question with no accepted answers, count in accepted rate

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer, accept-rate

I have posted some questions that are very narrow. If they even have an answer, it is one which doesn't really solve the problem.

Shouldn't there be a way to prevent those questions from counting in the accept rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that an accept rate between 80 and 100% is still acceptable (it has been discussed somewhere on meta). There are some questions I asked on which I can't accept an answer and in the end I still have a pretty good acceptance rate even thought it's not 100%.

Community wiki questions will not count in your accept rate but I think that outside of that there should not be a way to bypass this rate.

If most of your question can't be answered, leading to a very low acceptance rate, you should consider improving your way of asking questions or maybe realize that SO is not the place for such complicated questions.

You could also put a bounty on your question in order to try to get better answers...

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking that many questions that are so narrow that they don't get answers, then perhaps it's a reflection of the question?

You have a 100% percent accept rate on Stack Overflow. What's the issue?

[One of your questions on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/3097/ubuntu-pppoe-connection-timeout) is better suited for Super User (except for [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/30148/vps-server-missing-files), which belongs on Stack Overflow), maybe that's why they haven't been answered?

[The final question is so abstract](https://serverfault.com/questions/36293/centos-vps-virtual-memory-problems-diagnostics) that no one could ever provide an answer.